# Getting the equation for the line of intersection using Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a nasty expression that I am playing around with on Mathematica.

(-X + (2 X - X^2)/(
 2 (-1 + X)^2 ((1 + 2 (-1 + p) X - (-1 + p) X^2)/(-1 + X)^2)^(3/2)))/X

I graphed it along with the plane z = 0 where X and p are both restricted from 0 to 1:

Plot3D[{nasty equation is here, 0}, {p , 0, 1}, {X, 0, 1}]

I decided it would be interesting to obtain the equation for the intersection of the plane generated from the nasty equation and z = 0. So I used solve:

Solve[{that nasty equation == 0}, {p, X}, Reals]

and the output was even nastier with some results having the # symbol in it ( I have no idea what it is, and I am new to Mathematica). Is there a way to get an equation for the nice line of intersection between the nasty equation and z = 0 where p and X are restricted from 0 to 1? In the graph generated from Plot3D I see that the line of intersection appears to be some nice looking half parabola looking thing. I would like the equation for that if possible. Thank you!

Comment: You may start reading this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193 and this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complicated nasty equations Reduce is often more powerful and less likely to give you something that you will later find has hidden assumptions inside the result. Notice I include your constraint about the range of p and X to give Reduce the maximum amount of
information that I can to help it produce the simplest possible solution for you.

```
In[1]:= Reduce[(-X + (2 X-X^2)/(2 (-1 + X)^2 ((1 + 2 (-1 + p) X - (-1 + p) X^2)/
   (-1 + X)^2)^(3/2)))/X == 0 && 0 < X < 1 && 0 < p < 1, {X, p}]

Out[1]= 0<X<1 && p == Root[12 - 47*X + 74*X^2 - 59*X^3 + 24*X^4 - 4*X^5 + (-24 +
   108*X - 192*X^2 + 168*X^3 - 72*X^4 + 12*X^5)*#1 + (-48*X + 144*X^2 - 156*X^3 +
   72*X^4 - 12*X^5)*#1^2 + (-32*X^2 + 48*X^3 - 24*X^4 + 4*X^5)*#1^3 & , 1]
```

Root is a Mathematica function representing a root of a usually complicated polynomial
that would often be much larger if the actual root were written out in algebra, but we
can see whether the result is understandable enough to be useful by using ToRadicals.
Often Reduce will return several different alternatives using && (and) and || (or) to
let you see the details you must understand to correctly use the result.  See how I
copy the entire Root[...] and put that inside ToRadicals. Notice how Reduce returns
answers that include information about the ranges of variables. And see how I give Simplify the domain information about X to allow it to provide the greatest possible simplification.

```
In[2]:= Simplify[ToRadicals[Root[12 - 47 X + 74 X^2 - 59 X^3 + 24 X^4 - 4 X^5 +
   (-24 + 108 X - 192 X^2 + 168 X^3 - 72 X^4 + 12 X^5) #1 + (-48 X + 144 X^2 -
   156 X^3 + 72 X^4 - 12 X^5) #1^2 + (-32 X^2 + 48 X^3 - 24 X^4+ 4 X^5)#1^3&,1]],
   0 < X < 1]

Out[2]= (8*X - 24*X^2 + 26*X^3 - 12*X^4 + 2*X^5 + 2^(1/3)*(-((-2 + X)^8*(-1 +
   X)^2*X^3))^(1/3))/(2*(-2 + X)^3*X^2)
```

So your desired answer of where z= 0 will be where X is not zero, to avoid 0/0 in
your original equation, and where 0 < X < 1, 0 < p < 1 and where p is a root of that
final complicated expression in X. That result is a fraction and to be a root you
might take a look at where the numerator is zero to see if you can get any more
information about what you are looking for.

Sometimes you can learn something by plotting an expression. If you try to plot that final result you may end up with axes, but no plot. Perhaps the denominator is causing problems. You can try plotting just the numerator. You may again get an empty plot. Perhaps it is your cube root giving complex values. So you can put your numerator inside Re[] and plot that, then repeat that but using Im[]. Those will let you plot just the real and imaginary parts. You are doing this to try to understand where the roots might be. You should be cautious with plots because sometimes, particularly for complicated nasty expressions, the plot can make mistakes or hide desired information from you, but when used with care you can often learn something from this.

And, as always, test this and everything else very carefully to try to make sure that no mistakes have been made. It is too easy to "type some stuff into Mathematica, get some stuff  out", think you have the answer and have no idea that there are significant errors hidden.